# How can I upload a jpg file from computer to a chrome window using capybara?

Tags: google-chrome, capybara

I'm creating a test where I visit a website using chrome and when I click in one disabled button opens my documents page to upload a file. 
Using Capybara method of attach_file and page.attach_file nothing happens because he's trying to find the file at chrome window and he needs to find the file in the native modal.

How can I upload that file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with the native modal, you need to interact with the `<input type="file">` element on the page.  Find that input and then use `attach_file`

```
attach_file(`id or name of input`, `file_to_attach`)
```

If the file input is hidden on the page (common), then use the `make_visible` option

```
attach_file(`id or name of input`, `file_to_attach`, make_visible: true)
```